# SQL Showing Less information depending on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this code, what It returns is a list of some clients, but it lists too many. This is because it lists several of the same thing just with diffrent dates. I only want to show the latest date and none of the other ones. I tried to do a group by Client_Code but it didn't work, it just through up not an aggregate function or something similar (can get if needed). What I have been asked to get is all of our clients, with all the details listed. in the 'as' part and they all pull through properly. If I take out:

```
I.DATE_LAST_POSTED as 'Last Posted',
I.DATE_LAST_BILLED as 'Last Billed'
```

It shows up okay, but I need the last billed date only to appear. But putting these lines in shows the client several times listing all the diffrent bill dates. And I think that is because it is pulling across the diffrent Matters in the Matter_Master Table. Essentially, I would like to only show the Client Information on the highest Matter with there last billed date.

Please let me know if this needs clarification, im trying to explain best I can....

```
SELECT DISTINCT
A.DIWOR as 'ID',
B.Client_alpha_Name as 'Client Name',
A.ClientCODE as 'Client Code',
B.Client_address as 'Client Address',
D.COMM_NO AS 'Contact',
E.Contact_full_name as 'Possible Key Contact',
G.LOBSICDESC as 'LOBSIC Code',
H.EARNERNAME as 'Client Care Parnter',
A.CLIENTCODE + '/' + LTRIM(STR(A.LAST_MATTER_NUM)) as 'Last Matter Code',
I.DATE_LAST_POSTED as 'Last Posted',
I.DATE_LAST_BILLED as 'Last Billed'
FROM CLIENT_MASTER A
JOIN CLIENT_INFO B 
ON A.CLIENTCODE=B.CLIENT_CODE
JOIN MATTER_MASTER C
ON A.DIWOR=C.CLIENTDIWOR 
JOIN COMMINFO D
ON A.DIWOR=D.DIWOR
JOIN CONTACT E
ON A.CLIENTCODE=E.CLIENTCODE
JOIN VW_CONTACT F
ON E.NAME_DIWOR=F.NAME_DIWOR    
JOIN LOBSIC_CODES G
ON A.LOBSICDIWOR=G.DIWOR
JOIN STAFF H
ON A.CLIENTCAREPARTNER=H.DIWOR
JOIN MATTER I
ON C.DIWOR=I.MATTER_DIWOR
WHERE F.COMPANY_FLAG='Y'
AND C.MATTER_MANAGER NOT IN ('78','466','2','104','408','73','51','561','504','101','13','534','16','461','531','144','57','365','83','107','502','514','451')  
AND I.DATE_LAST_BILLED > 0
GROUP BY A.ClientCODE
ORDER BY A.DIWOR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't using enough aggregate functions.  Which is probably why you're using both the `DISTINCT` clause *and* the `GROUP BY` clause (the recommendation is to use `GROUP BY`, and not `DISTINCT`).

So... remove `DISTINCT`, add the necessary (unique, more or less) list of columns to the `GROUP BY` clause, and wrap the rest in aggregate functions, constants, or subselects.  In the specific case of wanting the largest date, wrap it in a `MAX()` function.

Comment: Thanks alot! This really helped, I didn't know you couldn't use Distinct and Group By together.

Comment: Well, actually, the problem is that you _can_, but that you _shouldn't_; doing so can potentially cause bizarre behaviour.  Generally, they're used to achieve the same (roughly) effect - specifying `DISTINCT` is the same as specifying `GROUP BY`, then listing every column.  When you're getting duplicate results, `DISTINCT` removes them.  However, it's usually better to refactor the query to remove the duplicates, using `GROUP BY` to roll things up, with subselects as necessary; this helps to explicitly spell out the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right:

```
--=======================
-- sample data - simplifed output of your query
--=======================
declare @t table
(
    ClientCode int,
    ClientAddress varchar(50),
    DateLastBilled datetime
    -- the rest of fields is skipped
)

insert into @t values (1, 'address1', '2011-01-01')
insert into @t values (1, 'address1', '2011-01-02')
insert into @t values (1, 'address1', '2011-01-03')
insert into @t values (1, 'address1', '2011-01-04')

insert into @t values (2, 'address2', '2011-01-07')
insert into @t values (2, 'address2', '2011-01-08')
insert into @t values (2, 'address2', '2011-01-09')
insert into @t values (2, 'address2', '2011-01-10')


--=======================
-- solution
--=======================
select distinct
    ClientCode,
    ClientAddress,
    DateLastBilled
from
(
    select 
        ClientCode,
        ClientAddress,
        DateLastBilled,
        -- list of remaining fields
        MaxDateLastBilled = max(DateLastBilled) over(partition by ClientCode)
    from 
    (
        -- here should be your query
        select * from @t
    ) t
) t
where MaxDateLastBilled = DateLastBilled
```